# Как сделать "клик на маркере -> карта центрируется и меняет масштаб, второй клик -> обратно"? React, Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leafletjs

По [этой ссылке](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-change-map-zoom-dynamically-when-clicking-on-a-marker-in-react-leaflet-v3x-skyxe?file=/src/App.js) карта с несколькими маркерами. По клику по любому маркеру карта увеличивает масштаб и центрируется. Как сделать, чтобы по второму клику на этом же маркере карта возвращалась в прежний масштаб и центр?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer, useMap } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

import "./styles.css";
import icon from "./constants";

function Markers({ data }) {
  const map = useMap();
  return (
    data.length > 0 &&
    data.map((marker, index) => {
      return (
        <Marker
          eventHandlers={{
            click: () => {
              map.setView(
                [
                  marker.geometry.coordinates[1],
                  marker.geometry.coordinates[0]
                ],
                14
              );
            }
          }}
          key={index}
          position={{
            lat: marker.geometry.coordinates[1],
            lng: marker.geometry.coordinates[0]
          }}
          icon={icon}
        >
          <Popup>
            <span>{marker.properties.label}</span>
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      );
    })
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/?q=paris&type=street")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.features);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={[47.217324, 13.097555]}
      zoom={4}
      scrollWheelZoom={false}
      style={{ height: "100vh" }}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />

      <Markers data={data} />
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:
При первом клике запомнить координаты центра в массив, а потом проверять его и либо использовать и обнулять, либо снова запоминать.

```
    <Marker
      eventHandlers={{
        click: () => {
          if (!centerCoords.length) {
            let mapCenter = map.getCenter();
            centerCoords.push(mapCenter.lat, mapCenter.lng)
            pointerCoords.push(marker.geometry.coordinates[1], marker.geometry.coordinates[0]);
            zoom = 14
          } else {
            pointerCoords = [...centerCoords];
            centerCoords.length = 0;
            zoom = 5
          }
          map.setView(
            pointerCoords,
            zoom
          );
        }
      }}
      key={index}
      position={{
        lat: marker.geometry.coordinates[1],
        lng: marker.geometry.coordinates[0]
      }}
      icon={icon}
    >
```